# Read JSON value with dynamic key using Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I want to read a `JSON` value using a dynamic key using Python. For example, I have a `JSON` in the following format

```
{
  "Personal": {
    "Address": {
      "City": "Newyork",
      "Country": "USA"
    }
  },
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  }
}
```

If I enter a string as "Personal.Address.City", I need to get city value using Python.

Comment: what specific problem are you facing? spliting the keys? parsing the json? accessing an element in a json object using a key? using a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have to split the key and look up level-by-level manually. I give two implementations below:

```
data = {
  "Personal": {
    "Address": {
      "City": "Newyork",
      "Country": "USA"
    }
  },
  "number": 123,
  "object": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  }
}

key = 'Personal.Address.City'

def lookup_dot_separated_key(data, key):
    value = data
    for k in key.split('.'):
        value = value[k]
    return value

print(lookup_dot_separated_key(data, key))

def lookup_key_list(data, keys):
    if keys:
        return lookup_key_list(data[keys[0]], keys[1:])
    else:
        return data

print(lookup_key_list(data, key.split('.')))
```